# Combine powershell output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to combine the output of two functions with the output of the default `Get-ADUser`-cmdlet. I'm interested in when an account was created, if it's locked and what it's name is. I also want to know when the user logged on for the last time (using multiple DC's) and if the account is being used as a shared mailbox.

I've written two custom functions `Get-ADUserLastLogon` and `isSharedMailbox`, both functions use the `Write-Output` function to output their output. In case of `Get-ADUserLastLogon` this will be *Lastlogon: time* and in case of `isSharedMailbox` this will be *shared: yes/no*. I'm also using a standard `Get-ADUser` call in a foreach loop

Now, the default output of `Get-ADUser` is:

> SAMAccountName    LockedOut    Created
>   --------------    ---------    -------
>   ACC                False    23-10-2015 8:20:20

Output of the custom functions is as following:

> Lastlogon : 1-1-1601 1:00:00
>
> Shared: yes

What I would like is to combine the LastLogon and Shared 'headers' to be combined into the Get-ADUser. So the output would become:

> SAMAccountName LockedOut Created LastLogon Shared

Code of current code, where the accounts get imported from an Excel sheet:

```
foreach($username in $usernameWithTld){
    if ($username -eq $NULL){
        break
    }

    $usernameWithoutTld = $username.split('\')

    Get-ADUser $usernameWithoutTld[1] -Properties LockedOut, SamAccountName, 
    Created -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object SAMAccountName, LockedOut, 
    Created

    Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $usernameWithoutTld[1]

   # Shared mailbox?

   isSharedMailbox -mailboxname $usernameWithoutTld[1]
}
```

Function code:

```
function isSharedMailbox([string]$mailboxname){
    $isObject = Get-ADUser  -Filter {name -eq $mailboxname} -SearchBase "..." | Select-Object DistinguishedName,Name

    if ($isObject -match "DistinguishedName"){
        $output = "Shared: no"
        Write-Output $output
    } else {
        $output = "Shared: No"
        Write-Output $output
    }

}


function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName){

  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  Write-Output "LastLogon : $dt"

}
```

I'm sure there are lots of improvements that can be made, I'm still learning how to write (proper) PowerShell. I hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: `isSharedMailbox` will always return `No`, might want to fix that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Calculated Property in your `Select-Object`. Have a look at [example 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object#example-4-select-the-name-and-start-day-of-processes) for the MSDN page.

In your case this would be:

```
Get-ADUser $usernameWithoutTld[1] -Properties LockedOut, SamAccountName, Created -ErrorAction Stop | `
Select-Object SAMAccountName, LockedOut, Created, @{Name='LastLogon';Expression={Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $usernameWithoutTld[1]}}, @{Name='IsSharedMailbox';Expression={isSharedMailbox -mailboxname $usernameWithoutTld[1]}}
```

Or even better, you can use the object(s) that `Get-ADUser` puts in the pipeline to in turn call your functions for that specific object, and can be useful in case your query returns multiple results:

```
Get-ADUser $usernameWithoutTld[1] -Properties LockedOut, SamAccountName, Created -ErrorAction Stop | `
Select-Object SAMAccountName, LockedOut, Created, @{Name='LastLogon';Expression={Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $_.sAMAccountName}}, @{Name='IsSharedMailbox';Expression={isSharedMailbox -mailboxname $_.sAMAccountName}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks alot for your explanation and solution! :)

Comment: @Brainscrewer, Is the script above works for OnPremise Only or Hybrid-Office365 ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to get your functions to return the values you are interested in, store them in variables, and combine everything together afterwards into a PSObject containing the properties you are interested.

The benefits of storing as an object are many. For example, you can use `Select-Object`, `Sort-Object` etc in the pipeline, or `Export-CSV` and other Cmdlets that expect `InputObject`

```
foreach($username in $usernameWithTld){
    if ($username -eq $NULL){
        break
    }

    $usernameWithoutTld = $username.split('\')

    $adDetails = Get-ADUser $usernameWithoutTld[1] -Properties LockedOut, SamAccountName, 
    Created -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object SAMAccountName, LockedOut, 
    Created

    $lastlogin = Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $usernameWithoutTld[1]

   # Shared mailbox?

   $isshared = isSharedMailbox -mailboxname $usernameWithoutTld[1]

   # putting together the PSobject
   [array]$myResults += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        SAMAccountName = $adDetails.SAMAccountName
        LockedOut      = $adDetails.LockedOut
        Created        = $adDetails.Created
        LastLogon      = $lastlogin
        Shared         = $shared # true/false or yes/no, depending on function
        #Shared         = if($shared){"yes"}else{"no"} # yes/no, based on true/false from function

   }
}
```

Functions:

```
function isSharedMailbox([string]$mailboxname){
    $isObject = Get-ADUser  -Filter {name -eq $mailboxname} -SearchBase "..." | Select-Object DistinguishedName,Name

    return ($isObject -match "DistinguishedName") # returns true/false

    <# if you prefer to keep yes/no
    if ($isObject -match "DistinguishedName"){
        return "Yes"  # no in original code
    } else {
        return "No"
    }
    #>
}

function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName){

  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)

  return $dt
  #Write-Output "LastLogon : $dt"

}
```

Comment: Is the script above works for OnPremise Only or Hybrid-Office365 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of the functions in global variables and finally concatenate them is one way.

Else you can use return the output from the function and use the value later or like : *$value= functionname* then $value will hold the return value of the function and later you can combine the results.

```
function isSharedMailbox([string]$mailboxname){
    $isObject = Get-ADUser  -Filter {name -eq $mailboxname} -SearchBase "..." | Select-Object DistinguishedName,Name

    if ($isObject -match "DistinguishedName"){
        $output = "Shared: no"
        $Global:result1= $output
    } else {
        $output = "Shared: No"
        $Global:result1= $output
    }

}


function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName){

  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  $Global:result2= "LastLogon : $dt"

}
## Calling the function . Change the placeholders accordingly
Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $usernameWithoutTld[1]
isSharedMailbox -mailboxname $usernameWithoutTld[1]

$FinalResult = "result1" + "result2"
$FinalResult
```

Hope it helps you better understanding.

Comment: I would not want to use global variables when a calculated property would be a much more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @JamesC.: Ya right. I just do not want to change any code on that context. :)